# Can a custom add-in execute code upon install of the .esriaddin

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.2, .net, add-in

I have made a custom add-in using C#.NET(a toolbar that contains buttons) and I was wondering if it is possible to have some code execute upon the install of the .esriaddin file. Basically I want to create a directory with some map templates on the users computer. I can just add the

```
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"Path"); etc....
```

to the on click event of the buttons and have it only execute if the folder doesn't exist but I was wondering if there was a way to execute it on install so I don't have to include it within the buttons.

Edit: I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604303/executing-an-installed-file-in-net-installer-class-event-handler) and it is similar though I'm not using a custom installer.

Comment: I always include an extension class in my AddIns and handle initialization methods in the Startup methdod (and in some cases the extension class's constructor if I need some early logging).

Comment: @Mapperz do you have the ability to migrate the question to SO?

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as off-topic seeing as it's directly related to ArcGIS development.

Comment: You'll want to create an 'extension' class and set it to inherit from ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension, then call startup code inside the OnStartup() function (declare this as protected overrides).